# One provisioning profile more than one team

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have been working with one team under apple developers program, using lot of provisioning profile when developing apple applications.

For some reason we needed to create another team but I would like to have both teams to share all the provisioning profiles.

**Do you think it is possible?**

I tried to download one provisioning profile and upload to the new team with no success :(

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible.

The provisioning profiles are associated with one team as can be seen from the com.apple.developer.team-identifier included in the profile. This field isn't an array.

```
<key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
<string>4JDWF27F87</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

The team admin can add the people in other team as members of their team in apple's [member center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter) and approve their development certificates requests so that they can use the same provisioning profiles. Apple has explained this process here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html#

But this is when you want to use the same profile for both the teams..ideally for a different team a separate team provisioning profile should be created.

Comment: it says nothing about that :S